# How to let C# designer edit my struct property?

Tags: c#, winforms, struct, properties, designer

I am creating a custom Windows Forms control in C# with several custom properties. One of those properties is a simple struct with several integral fields:

```
public struct Test
{
    public int A, B;
}

Test _Test;

[Category("MyCategory")]
public Test TestProperty
{
    get { return _Test; }
    set { _Test = value; }
}
```

I want the Visual Studio designer to edit the fields of my structure the same way as it does for `Size`, `Margins` and other similar Windows Forms structures. Do I need to implement a custom property editor based on `UITypeEditor` class, or is there some common "structure editor" provided by .Net framework?

Comment: rather than update your title to solved you should add your own answer and, if it is the best one, mark it as the accepted answer.  This will help others who have the same problem in the future more than simply editing your question.  It will also take it out of the "unanswered" list where many of us go to find people that have questions we can help with.

Comment: Tried. Got a message "new users must wait 8 hours before answering their own questions".

Comment: *@sharp* you do not need to answer to your question, but check the most usefull answer

Comment: @sharp - you don't need to edit the title to say `solved`, just wait till your 8 hours is up then add it as an answer, then wait whatever stand-down period there is before marking it as the answer.

Comment: @slugster Seems to be quite a hassle to do such a simple thing. Waiting and coming back to it 2 times is definitely not what I want to do. Can I just manually close or delete the question without all that complications?

Comment: @sharp, those restrictions are only in place for new users, stick around and earn some rep and they won't apply anymore. It's not good form to just delete a question especially if someone has already answered it, as the answer(s) may help future users. You don't have to post your answer straight away, you can do it sometime in the future when you are browsing the site or asking another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public struct Test
{
    public int _A, _B;
    public int B
    {
        get { return _B; }
        set { _B = value; }
    }
    public int A
    {
        get { return _A; }
        set { _A = value; }
    }
}

Test _Test;

[Category("MyCategory")]
public Test TestProperty
{
    get { return _Test; }
    set { _Test = value; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, applying [Serializable] to the struct declaration is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own designer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx