Why Designer does not store custom structure values
Why doesn't the designer store DesignTime values when using a Structure instead of a Class?
I have this code:
<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
Public Structure ABC
    Public Property Prop1 As Integer
    Public Property Prop2 As String
    Public Property Prop3 As Boolean
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Prop2
    End Function
End Structure

<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
Public Class XYZ
    Public Property Prop1 As Integer
    Public Property Prop2 As String
    Public Property Prop3 As Boolean
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Prop2
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyControl
    Inherits Control
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property ABCs As New ObjectModel.Collection(Of ABC)
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property XYZs As New ObjectModel.Collection(Of XYZ)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(e As EventArgs)
        For Each a As ABC In ABCs
            Debug.WriteLine("ABC :" & a.Prop2)
        Next

        For Each x As XYZ In XYZs
            Debug.WriteLine("XYZ :" & x.Prop2)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

The designer only stores XYZ values and will not store ABC values.
Here is the designer code
'MyControl1
'
Me.MyControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
Me.MyControl1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray
Me.MyControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(150, 216)
Me.MyControl1.Name = "MyControl1"
Me.MyControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(182, 123)
Me.MyControl1.TabIndex = 2
Me.MyControl1.Text = "MyControl1"
Xyz1.Prop1 = 0
Xyz1.Prop2 = "Test"
Xyz1.Prop3 = False
Me.MyControl1.XYZs.Add(Xyz1)


"Why" questions are rarely a good fit for Stack Overflow, since the only way to get an authoritative answer is getting the attention of someone on the engineering team for the product. Anything else is "opinion based", which is explicitly off topic here and leads to the question getting closed. You should think about re-wording this to ask something that can be answered in an authoritative way.

My apologies .this is caused by using an online translator.

@JoelCoehoorn: This isn’t that kind of “why” question.

I poked around and found something in C# that might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094595/how-to-let-c-sharp-designer-edit-my-struct-property
